# Webstorm File Watchers repeats calling batch file for ever

Tags: javascript, batch-file, ant, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

[image]

I am using File Watchers within Webstorm for calling a batch file.
This batch file contains an Ant call command like this:

```
call ant  "clean" "debug" "compress" -f C:\Users\cm\workspace2\Games\jsfiles\PokerGame\build\build.xml
```

File Watchers triggers every time I save changed js files and does not stop it calls and for ever.

The picture shows my configuration for File Watcher in Webstorm.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a supposition: the IDE sees the .js files generated by ant (as a result of 'compress' target running) and, as it watches .js files, runs the watcher again and again... Try excluding the directory where your minified files are created from watcher scope - create a new scope (Settings/scopes) with this folder excluded and then set this scope to your file watcher

Comment: thank you for the answer, you are right!
I created a custom scope for File Watchers and I included to this scope only the files I work with. So the compressed files and everyelse that I do not need are excluded from the scope.
Thank you again!